# PLINQ and the logical processors

Tags: c#, .net, plinq, processors

My system's configuration is this: **Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3820QM CPU @ 2.70GHz, 2694 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)**

You may notice that my machine has 4 cores and 8 logical processors.

If I'm going to use a PLINQ query to take advantage of the parallelism, can I specify 7 for the **WithDegreeOfParallelism** so the query will take advantage of all the logical processors by creating one thread for each logical processor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't have to tell `PLINQ` how many logical processors you have. It already knows (using `Environment.ProcessorCount`), and it will optimize the query accordingly. The intention of `WithDegreeOfParallelism` is to control what `PLINQ` doesn't know, for example if your code is mainly `I/O` intensive and not `CPU` intensive.
2. You *can* do that if you insist.
3. If you have 8 processors why would you limit it to 7?

Comment: To answer your 3rd question, does not matter 7 or 8. I just left one if other apps are going to starve.

Comment: @wonderfulworld there's no need to do that. Your threads have a time slice to run in and the OS worries about starvation. you should use the resources it gives you as much as you can. So if your code is CPU intensive leave it at 8 (the default in PLINQ), if it's IO intensive then you probably need a higher number.

Comment: Thanks. My understand is that CPU bound operations need to be paralleled but not IO. Am I wrong?

Comment: @wonderfulworld CPU bound operations get faster when you add cores, IO ones mostly don't. That means the you **shouldn't** do more CPU bound operation than your cores, but you **can** do more IO ones (as long as they are asynchronous)

Comment: @I3arnon And as long as the IO-bound operation can take advantage of parallelism. For example, reading from a disk will typically get *slower* with more threads.